# AES decryption not working with crypto.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, hex, cryptojs

i am trying to get decrypted data with crypto-js but getting blank. while same keys works online aes decryption.

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js"); 
var key = '+MbQeThVmYq3t6w9z$C&F)J@NcRfUjXn';
var iv = '5ty76ujie324$567';
var encdata = 'ad06c28a5c9d933bc73451f86fcaa69a';
cipher = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(encdata))
var decrypt = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipher, Buffer.from(key), {
iv: iv,
mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});

var ddd = decrypt.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
console.log(ddd,"hey");
```

unable to understand why it is behaving like this. but if i use crypto it is working with below code

```
var crypto = require("crypto");
 let encryptedText = Buffer.from(encdata, 'hex');
        let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(key), iv);
        let decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedText);
        decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]);
       console.log(decrypted.toString());
```

Comment: This might help you. [CryptoJS and key/IV length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512858/cryptojs-and-key-iv-length)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Key and IV must be passed as `WordArray`-objects (and not as strings or NodeJS-buffer) [[1]](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input). Since both are specified as UTF8-strings, they can be converted into `WordArray`-objects with the corresponding UTF8-encoder (`CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(...)`) [[2]](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders):

```js
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('+MbQeThVmYq3t6w9z$C&F)J@NcRfUjXn');         // Key: Use a WordArray-object instead of a UTF8-string / NodeJS-buffer 
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('5ty76ujie324$567');                          // IV: Use a WordArray-object instead of a UTF8-string 
var encdata = 'ad06c28a5c9d933bc73451f86fcaa69a';
var cipher = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(encdata));   

var decrypt = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipher, key, {
  iv: iv,
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});

var decrypted = decrypt.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
console.log(decrypted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Note that the ciphertext is usually passed as `CipherParams`-object [[1]](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input). Alternatively, it can be passed as a string (like in this example), which is then *implicitly* converted into a `CipherParams`-object with a definable format strategy (by default, a Base64 encoded string is expected).

The decryption returns a `WordArray` to be converted into a UTF8-string [[4]](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-output):